# How many integers can you represent with 6 bits?

Tags: combinatorics, numeral-representations

I might be wrong but I think it must be 2^6 = 64 integers?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you use the bits to represent numbers, doesn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos If the question is "can", you can reasonable talk about upper and lower bounds for *any* representation. Both are trivial here, assuming you have had any amount of exposure to combinatorics.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, and I was trying to introduce the OP to this kind of conversation, hopefully helping him/her rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is 64 integers. If you are representing only positive integers​ then you can represent 0 to 63. If you are representing negative numbers also, then you must use 2's complement representation because it is the best and it is the standard format used in computers​. Two's complement covers from -32 to +31, which is also 64 integers. If you use some other representation for signed numbers, like 1's complement & signed magnitude representation, then you will lose one integer because zero has two representations in these (ie., one for +0 & the other is -0). Because other schemes waste one integer place, only 2's complement representation is used for signed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's treat this as a combinatorics problem, so you can see how you get $2^6$:

- Each bit has 2 possible values, 0 or 1
- There are 6 bits that we can choose a value for
- The choice of value for each of these is independent, so we can find the total number of choices by multiplying the number choices for each bit together.

So, there are $2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2 = 2^6 $ possible values. How you map these values onto integers is up to you.

Comment: You've shown there are 64 bit patterns, but you did not show each bit pattern corresponds to a unique value. As Ch.Siva Ram Kishore points out, there are at least two such mappings in common use (positive values only and two's complement) so the conclusion is valid.